# How to convert delegate `Func<T1, Func<T2, Task<TResult>>>` to `Func<T1, Task<Func<T2, TResult>>`?

Tags: c#, async-await, higher-order-functions

For my delegate (with signature `Func<T1, Func<T2, Task<TResult>>`) to be applicable it has to confirm to the signature `Func<T1, Task<TResult>>`.  I would like to have a function such as:

```
public static Func<T1, Task<Func<T2, TResult>> TaskToOuterScope<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<T1, Func<T2, Task<TResult>>> f)
{
    // throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

How to implement this `TaskToOuterScope`-function?

I tried:

```
public static Func<T1, Task<Func<T2, TResult>> TaskToOuterScope<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<T1, Func<T2, Task<TResult>>> f)
{
    return async (T1 arg1) => await (async (T2 arg2) => await f(arg1)(arg2));
}
```

However, this gives CS4001 Cannot await 'lambda expression'.

Googling gave pages that are either about currying (the signature `Func<T1, Func<T2, Task<TResult>>` is the result from currying) or about async/await but non about the combination or more specifically about moving task to outer scope in higher order functions.

Is conversion from `Func<T1, Func<T2, Task<TResult>>` to `Func<T1, Task<Func<T2, TResult>>>` possible?
And if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

`Task<TResult>` is a task whose result depends on two parameters, `t1` and `t2`. You can see that you cannot transform it to a task `Task<Func<T2, TResult>>` whose result only depends on one parameter `t1`.

Whatever asynchronous task is being executed requires (by the definition you have given) those two parameters upfront before it starts executing. It cannot take `t1` then, given `t2` at a later point, return its result synchronously.

Comment: This logic is correct but we can simplify it further by noticing that T1 plays no part in the asynchrony; the question is the same as "can I convert `Func<T2, Task<T3>>` to `Task<Func<T2, T3>>` ?"  And now we can apply your same logic: the former requires a T2 to reach some asynchronous operation, and there's no way to turn that into something that asynchronously returns a synchronous operation.